# DDD - service specialization

Tags: c#, service, repository, domain-driven-design, paas

I am writing a multi-tenancy Platform As A Service solution, and trying to employ DDD approach. I have some basic, Core functionality which is default behaviour and has its services exosed to an API (application) layer.
So far it all was straightforward, until I've started to write per-tenant, custom functionality (separated projects on top of Core). How do I extend base services to add custom behaviour?

For example, `Core` service:

```
namespace Core.Services
{
    public class UserService
    {
        private readonly IUserRepository userRepository;

        public User Get(Guid id)
        {
            userRepository.GetById(id);
        }

        public void Update(Guid id, UserStatus newUserStatus)
        {
            userRepository.UpdateStatus(Guid id, newUserStatus);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I have a `ClientA`, who wants to, say, periodically rename users based on their activity:

```
namespace ClientA.Services
{
    public class UserService // : Core.UserService ?
    {
        public void RenameInactiveUsers()
        {
            // something like
            userRepository.UpdateAll(
                condition: (user) => { user.NotActiveRecently() },
                action: (user) => { user.Name = user.Name + " (inactive)" }
            )
        }

        public void BanSuspiciousUsers()
        {
            userRepository.UpdateAll(
                condition: (user) => { user.SomeSuspiciousFlag },
                action: (user) => { user.Status = UserStatus::Banned }
            );
        }

        // etc
    }
}
```

So, how do I extend base services while still expose `Get`, `Update` and other methods to reuse the code?

Should it be inheritance? That way I will have to make private repositories, data and methods accessible in ancestors. Furthermore, inheritance in discourage in DDD as far as I know.

Or should for each tenant I create new `UserService`, which takes `Core.UserService` and expose identical contract, which will lead to many code like

`ClientA.UserService.Get(id) { return udnerlyingUserService.Get(id); }` ?

Maybe, some third option?

Answer (score 0):

first do not use userRepository at the ClientA service to separate the business from the infrastructure layer.

the implementation in the clientA can only be a simple call to the service : Core.userService and at that level you make the call to the repository.